# Workspace stays fixed on external monitor, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces

My laptop is connected to two external monitors. When I switch workspaces, only the main monitor will switch, and the second monitor will stay fixed.

Since I want to switch between several task, each requiring the use of two monitors, this is really annoying.

I found another similar question here for Ubuntu 11.10. The answer provided was to execute the command:

> gconftool-2 --set
>   /desktop/gnome/shell/windows/workspaces_only_on_primary false --type
>   bool

and re-login.

I managed to execute the command (no errors), but the problem continued even after a re-login.

Is this solvable on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides workspaces-only-on-primary false
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
Open up dconf editor, org > gnome > shell > overrides, uncheck workspaces-only-on-primary